# Referencing variables inside maps and iterating over them

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to reference two secrets from berglas, put them into a `map` and then iterate through them in my resource `compute_tunnels`:

```
data "berglas_secret" "tunnel_key_1" {
  bucket  = "my-bucket"
  name    = "tunnel1"
}
data "berglas_secret" "tunnel_key_2" {
  bucket  = "my-bucket"
  name    = "tunnel2"
}


variable "tunnel_map" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    1 = {
      "shared_secret" : data.berglas_secret.tunnel_key_1
    }
    2 = {
      "shared_secret" : data.berglas_secret.tunnel_key_2
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_vpn_tunnel" "compute_tunnels" {
  for_each = var.tunnel_map
  shared_secret = each.value
}
```

However I am getting an error `Variables may not be used here.` in my declaration of `map`. What is the correct syntax for doing this iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't dynamically** create any `var` variables. The `var` variables must be static. But you can do so for `local` variables. So your `tunnel_map` should be `local` variable if you want to create its values dynamically:

```
locals {

  tunnel_map = {
    1 = {
      "shared_secret" : data.berglas_secret.tunnel_key_1
    }
    2 = {
      "shared_secret" : data.berglas_secret.tunnel_key_2
    }
  }

}

resource "google_compute_vpn_tunnel" "compute_tunnels" {
  for_each = local.tunnel_map
  shared_secret = each.value
}
```